# Strimzi Kafka compatible with Azure storage classes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I am deploying a Kafka cluster (using the [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html#configuration-points-broker_str) CRD) that copies data from another cluster using the `KafkaMirrorMaker` on `Azure`. The problem is that when Kafka is restarted, the data is lost. I am using persistent Volumes claims (which worked for me in all other cases) and so I am very unsure where the problem is.

While looking through the [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html#configuration-points-broker_str) documents I found a sentence where it said:

> "Strimzi requires block storage provisioned through StorageClass. The
> file system format for storage must be XFS or EXT4. Three types of
> data storage are supported:"[just below 5.3].

Could the problem be, that my storage class has the wrong file system?
I can not find out which filesystems the different Azure storage classes use. Does anyone know if this could cause a problem (or is `XFS/EXT4` a standard that everyone uses)?

I can not find anything of relevant information in the logs.
In case anyone wants to see here is how I define my Kafka storage, where `default-hdd-reatin` is a self-defined storage class (which worked in other cases):

```
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 500Gi
      deleteClaim: false
      class: default-hdd-retain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the standard `storageClass` has an EXT4 file system so there is no problem here.